# Rails console won't let me continue typing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console

I am trying to just use the Rails console to access my User and set him as an admin and skip the authorization email process.

So I typed:

```
rails c
```

Then it never lets me type in something else until I quit the console.

Here is the output of the console

```
encrypted_password:
  "$2a$10$6KRoGrk3fjW3IMLS122pUuvOakx5.xBwiOLzuNrPufBtBzkqpXnkO",
reset_password_token: nil,
reset_password_sent_at: nil,
remember_created_at: nil,
sign_in_count: 0,
current_sign_in_at: nil,
last_sign_in_at: nil,
current_sign_in_ip: nil,
last_sign_in_ip: nil,
confirmation_token:
  "da05c95ad42b7d305f265a92deb36957183c5670c4f24180c1eb83fc4e6e33bc",
confirmed_at: nil,
confirmation_sent_at: Mon, 06 Apr 2015 20:32:04 UTC +00:00,
unconfirmed_email: nil,
created_at: Mon, 06 Apr 2015 20:32:04 UTC +00:00,
updated_at: Mon, 06 Apr 2015 20:32:04 UTC +00:00,
role: nil,
avatar: nil,
image: nil,
user_id: nil>
~
(END)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound right.

The *outout* you provide looks like part of a Rails ActiveRecord object, which means that the console did load something.

Could you at least type `User.find(whatever)`? It's not clear in the question.

Anyway, when the console let's you *scroll* with <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd>, it's because it's acting like the `less` CLI software. Just press the <kbd>q</kbd> key to go resume entering commands.

Comment: Thank you so much. Hitting q key worked, so I could enter more commands.

Comment: Quick Question. What is the command for skipping a confirmation email. What do I need to type in the rails console to skip the email confirmation step and just validate the user in the console. So I can login?

Comment: It depends on how you're managing user registrations. Looks like you're using Devise, you should find something in the Devise wiki on github.

Comment: Anyway, StackOverflow follows a "question-Answers" model, and answered questions will remain available in the future, for people searching the site. If you need help for this new issue, you should ask a new question rather than add _off topic_ comments to this one.